# Validation of Postman response data with an input JSON

Tags: postman

I have a input json file like below:

```
{
    "interfaceIndex": "1234",
    "portName": "1/2/3",
    "portType": "LAN",
    "adminStatus": "up",
    "operStatus": "down",
    "managementPort": "No",
    "primaryRack": "1",
    "primarySlot": "8",
    "primaryPort": "5",
    "secondaryRack": "",
    "secondarySlot": "",
    "secondaryPort": "",
    "protectionMode": "",
    "sfpDescription": "test",
    "speed": "0",
    "neType": "test1",
    "oldAdminStatus": "",
    "portDisplayName": "LAN 1/2/3",
    "deviceVariant": "test11"
}
```

Below is the request body through postman

```
{

   "neName": "{{neName}}",
   "primarySlot": "2", 
   "primaryPort": "3" 
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "interfaceIndex": "1234",
    "neName": "BA12",
    "neIp": "1.1.1.1",
    "context": "",
    "portName": "1/2/3",
    "portType": "LAN",
    "adminStatus": "up",
    "operStatus": "",
    "managementPort": "No",
    "primaryRack": "1",
    "primarySlot": "2",
    "primaryPort": "3",
    "secondaryRack": "",
    "secondarySlot": "",
    "secondaryPort": "",
    "protectionMode": "",
    "sfpDescription": "",
    "speed": "0",
    "neType": "test1",
    "oldAdminStatus": "",
    "portDisplayName": "LAN 1/2/3",
    "deviceVariant": "test11"
}
```

I want to validate the API response data with the input.json. Till now i have done something like:

```
pm.test("Validate interfaceIndex", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.interfaceIndex).to.eql(data['interfaceIndex']);
});
pm.test("Validate neName", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.neName).to.eql(pm.environment.get("neName2"));
});
pm.test("Validate neIp", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.neIp).to.eql(pm.environment.get("neIp"))
});
.....
```

But without hardcoding the key in the tests i want to loop through each items in the response data and want to match with the input.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison Loop: The loop iterates over each key-value pair in the `inputJson` object using `Object.entries(inputJson)`.

the response received from the API matches the expected structure and values specified in the `inputJson`. If all attributes and their values match, the test passes. If there's any discrepancy, the test fails, indicating that the response structure or values are not as expected.

This `tests` code can validate your data

```json
const inputJson = {
    "interfaceIndex": "1234",
    "portName": "1/2/3",
    "portType": "LAN",
    "adminStatus": "up",
    "operStatus": "down",
    "managementPort": "No",
    "primaryRack": "1",
    "primarySlot": "8",
    "primaryPort": "5",
    "secondaryRack": "",
    "secondarySlot": "",
    "secondaryPort": "",
    "protectionMode": "",
    "sfpDescription": "test",
    "speed": "0",
    "neType": "test1",
    "oldAdminStatus": "",
    "portDisplayName": "LAN 1/2/3",
    "deviceVariant": "test11"
}
const outputJson = pm.response.json();

for (const [inputKey, inputValue] of Object.entries(inputJson)) {
    console.log("input \"" + inputKey + "\" : \"" + inputValue + "\" ==> \"" + outputJson[inputKey]);
    pm.expect(outputJson[inputKey]).to.eql(inputJson[inputKey]);
}
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated, I want to import the input.json and then want to match the data. I dont want to add the json in the test script

Comment: Import from API, environment variable  or file? Postman can't import from a file.

Comment: I want to the import the input.json file as Data file in Run Collection

Comment: Run collection is whole test sequence (request with data) export or import not a data only import.

Comment: Your test seems like can test by node.js. I will update my answer if you want.

Comment: That is fine. I am accepting your existing answer